# How to find if two arrays are from uncorrelated distributions?

Tags: scipy, p-value, hypothesis-test, pearson-correlation, numpy-random

I have two arrays - `array1` and `array2`. How confidently can I state that they are generated from uncorrelated distributions? Just checking the correlation values would not suffice; I would require p-values as well.

Thought of using the following method -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array2 = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

# Calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient and p-value
res = pearsonr(array1, array2, alternative='two-sided')

correlation_coefficient, p_value = res.statistic, res.pvalue

# Print the results
print(f"Pearson Correlation Coefficient: {correlation_coefficient}")
print(f"P-value: {p_value}")

# Define the confidence level (e.g., 95%)
confidence_level = 0.95

# Make a conclusion based on the p-value
if p_value < (1 - confidence_level):
    print(f"I am {confidence_level * 100}% confident that these two arrays are correlated.")
```

The output -

```
Pearson Correlation Coefficient: -1.0
P-value: 0.0
I am 95.0% confident that these two arrays are correlated.
```

However one problem with this approach is found in the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy-stats-pearsonr) statement -

> This function also performs a test of the null hypothesis that the
> distributions underlying the samples are uncorrelated and normally
> distributed.

I just want to test the hypothesis that the distributions underlying the samples are uncorrelated without caring about the nature of the distributions - normal or anything else.

Is there any alternative that solves this issue?

---

## Two tentative solutions

### Simulate the distribution of uncorrelated arrays

I can generate two random arrays (of same length as `array1`) and calculate their correlation. By repeating this many times I can get a distribution of the correlation values amongst uncorrelated arrays, without any reference to the underlying distribution type. I can use this distribution to get the p-value of the actual observed correlation between `array1` and `array2`.

Of course the distribution followed by `numpy` random generators might have an impact. Besides, I want to avoid so much coding if a solution is already present.

### Can I use `method` parameter of `scipy.stats.pearsonr`?

Am not sure what `method` parameter of `pearsonr` does. Particularly when `method` is set to `PermutationMethod`. Is that somehow a solution to my query?

Comment: By passing a `MonteCarloMethod` for `method`,  `pearsonr` can do something 
similar to what you said in your first tentative solution, but yes, the distribution might matter. Using `PermutationMethod` is similar, but rather than random samples from a distribution of your choice, it uses random *permutations* of one of your arrays. (Under the null hypothesis that there is no correlation, all would have been equally likely.) More about the theory is in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/resampling.html, but if you'd like, I can write an answer with some code.

Comment: @MattHaberland Thanks for the clarification. You can present a complete answer as well. I feel it would be more clarifying and useful across the general audience. But I would leave that to your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by calculating the observed value of the statistic:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array2 = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

# Calculate the observed value of the statistic
res = stats.pearsonr(array1, array2, alternative='two-sided')
observed = res.statistic  # observed value of the statistic 
observed  # -1.0
```

This seems pretty extreme, but we need to quantify the probability of obtaining such an extreme value due to chance. A permutation test does this without making an assumption about the forms of the distributions from which the data were sampled.

If the samples are from independent distributions, any value observed in the second array was equally likely to have been paired with any value observed in the first array. Accordingly, the null hypothesis of the permutation test is that all possible pairings were equally likely, and the observed pairings were sampled at random. By computing the statistic for each permutation of the second array w.r.t. the first, we obtain the null distribution of the statistic.

```py
import itertools
rng = np.random.default_rng(4259845268735019)
null_distribution = []
for resample in itertools.permutations(array2):
    res = stats.pearsonr(array1, resample)
    null_distribution.append(res.statistic)
null_distribution = np.asarray(null_distribution)
```

The (one-sided) p-value corresponding with the alternative that distributions are dependent with positive/negative correlation is the fraction of the null distribution greater/less than or equal to the observed statistic value. The two-sided p-value is twice the minimum of the two.

```py
pvalue_greater = (null_distribution >= observed).sum() / len(null_distribution)
pvalue_less = (null_distribution <= observed).sum() / len(null_distribution)
pvalue = 2 * min(pvalue_greater, pvalue_less)
pvalue  # 0.016666666666666666
```

The null distribution happens to be symmetric about 0, so you may prefer to think of the two-sided p-value the fraction of statistic values "more extreme" (in either direction) than the observed value of the statistic.

```
(abs(null_distribution) >= abs(observed)).sum() / len(null_distribution)
# 0.016666666666666666
```

This is essentially what `pearsonr` does under the hood when you pass `method='PermutationMethod'`.

```py
res = stats.pearsonr(array1, array2, alternative='two-sided', method=stats.PermutationMethod())
res.pvalue  # 0.016666666666666666
```

As the arrays get larger, the number of permutations grows quickly. By default, ['PermutationMethod'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.PermutationMethod.html) does no more than 9999 resamples, opting for randomized permutations if this is not exhaustive. You can change this using the `n_resamples` parameter of `PermutationMethod`.

Consider avoiding a statement like "I am 95.0% confident that these two arrays are correlated" and instead reporting the full p-value and how you obtained it.